# Android new Bottom Navigation implementation

Tags: android, material-design

Is there any way to implement bottom navigation tab as per the google new guideline (Pure android). Is there any example.?

I searched and found [this tutorial](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/) and [this one](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation-part-2/) also but it user external library, is there anyway to implement it native with android support library ??

Google Link: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the support library doesn't have BottomBar yet and I wouldn't wait for it.

That 3rd party library you mentioned is pretty simple. If you don't want to use it, but you'd like to have a BottomBar in your app, just analyze the sources and implement a similiar component in your app.

Comment: Thanks so i will use this one i mentioned, it's really pretty simple

Comment: Here we go: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html